# Pacman packages corrupted

Tags: arch-linux

I am trying to install Arch in a Virtual Box on a Windows 10 host and it appears that pacman does not work no matter what mirrors I have in /erc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.

I get multiple lines like

error: could not read db 'core' (Damaged tar archive)
error: could not read db 'extra' (Damaged tar archive)
error: could not read db 'community' (Damaged tar archive)

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Did you mean `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`? Have you checked the [status of the mirrors](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrors/status/)?  Did you refresh the package lists with `pacman -Syy`? Have you tried downloading other files (with curl or wget) that have a checksum or signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by uninstalling all Hyper-V related features from Windows and disabling hardware acceleration in the VM settings.

Apparently some issue between VirtualBox and Windows affects cryptographic calculations but otherwise has no apparent effect on VM execution. I find that quit disconcerting.